# Filtering mutiple rows and counting rows with class to change progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I have been working on a project and learning some Bootstrap allong the way but i'm at a point now that I realy need your help. I'm a complete noob when it gets to jquery so I will just get to it :

My [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/R3nierjvr/poz9dwhg/) will Explain all

1. The First Problem is the progress bar, I need it to be dynamic I
   have already set the table up then when marked complete a row will
   get  class of :"success" what I trying to do is have the progress
   bar count the rows with class "success and show progress so far so
   if 4 rows in 10 have a class of success then the progress bar should
   read 40%.

Here is what my progress bar is now :

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">70%</div>
</div>
```

2. I need to be able to apply filters to the table but I should also be able to apply more than 1 filter at a time : example would be seeing all "Side quests" in "region a" but only "uncompleted" ones between "lvl 1 - 10"

I have set up my filter menus laready with classes for each filter menu aswell as some menu's with data- attribute.

any help will be awsome!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/poz9dwhg/67/ progressbar fixed

Comment: thats awsome and quick thx, mind if I ask if you can explain a spessfic part: I understand you used the .legth to count will I be able to show the number of counts for "success" class at the bottom there is an area in the footer just not an amount still wanted to ask that...

Comment: if you have array of your table records, then you can use array.forEach and array.filter to filter your data and create new array of filtered records and then re-render your table with the new array

Comment: I understoof this : ???? . sorry learning here. by aray do you mean like a csv file ?

Comment: No I mean javascript arrays. and quest counter fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/poz9dwhg/70/

Comment: oh ok sry....lol like I said Jquery noob. Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this is a solution for your point 1 (progress bar) in the question.

The below javascript does the job for progress bar, [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/poz9dwhg/69/)

You should start the progress bar with 0 initially in the html

```
var successRows = $(this).parents("tbody").children(".success").length;
var totalRows = $(this).parents("tbody").children("tr").length;
var progressPerc = ((successRows / totalRows) * 100) + "%";
$(".progress-bar").width(progressPerc).text(progressPerc);
```